# Matching existing leads to new accounts on salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-flow

I have a question regarding matching existing leads with new customer accounts (PersonAccount) being created.

I need to create a flow where if a new customer account (PersonAccount) is created, a flow needs to check whether there is a matching lead to link the two together, and then convert the lead to an account (PersonAccount).

The Criteria is as follows:

1. When a new Customer Account (PersonAccount) record is created, a flow looks to see if there is a matching existing Lead record, matching on email address and first and last names.
2. If a match is found, the related Lead record is linked to the Customer Account (PersonAccount) record.
3. I have created a lookup field on the Customer Account (PersonAccount) called Lead.

I found a help Article but really struggling with getting the decision tree to work.
https://www.revenuehero.io/blog/set-up-lead-to-account-matching-in-salesforce

Any help on this would be much appreciated. I know usually first the Lead is created and then is converted to a customer, However my company uses leads differently

I've tried using the AppExchange package (Relate Leads to Accounts) that relates a Lead record to an Account record and tried to change the flows by looking for a match between the Lead's email address instead of the leads email **domain** however this did not work for me.